# Why doesn't Windows XP show "Total Size" and "Free Space" for USB flash disks?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, usb-flash-drive, disk-space

When I double click on `My Computer`, I can immediately see the `Total size` and `Free space` for internal and external HDDs, and inserted CD/DVD media, but in the same columns I cannot see these values for any USB flash drives. They are just empty. To see, I have to right click on USB drive letter, and select `Properties`.

Is there a trick to make Windows XP display USB drive's `Total size` and `Free space` in `My Computer` window?

[image]

Comment: Is it in FAT32?

Comment: Yes, Flash Drive is FAT32 whereas HDD is NTFS.

Comment: I'M pretty sure that if you format it in NTFS, you will see the information of that USB drive. Can you try it out?

Comment: I have to use it in FAT32 because I use it for my XBOX360 and LCD TV.
I wanted to try your recommendation as well but I cannot format it as NTFS. When I right click and select Format, the only File System I can select for it is FAT32.

Comment: It's weird. I have Windows 7 as you have and I am able to format my 4go and 16go in NTFS. In that case, I'm 99% sure that have it format in NTFS would fix the issue. But if you can't afford due to Xbox, I understand ;)

Comment: @Mehper: I suppose it's the behavior of XP not to show free space and total size on Removable Disk. Maybe because at the time XP was released, removable drives were slow and it would take a lot of time to parse them to calculate the used space. Even more on FAT where this info is not stored in the metadata but has to be calculated each time. I think it's stored in the metadata for NTFS. And the speed of removable devices has improved too.

Comment: :) Yes, my constraint is Xbox, I am dependent to FAT32. By the way, I tried a SanDisk Cruzer Micro 4 GB, and a Kingston 1 GB. They can't be formatted as NTFS neither.  
I am starting to believe that WinXP cannot display FAT32 drives' total size and free space in My Computer view.

Comment: @Snark: This seems reasonable. You may think of pasting this as an answer as you determine the behavior of XP against FAT32 drives.

Comment: @Mehper: I didn't find yet literature to back my suppositions...

Comment: Me neither tho...

Comment: FYI, even when formatted as NTFS, XP still does not show the size and free space (nor does Windows 7).  Also, in order to format a USB drive as NTFS, it has to set have its hardware setting at "Optimize for performance".  To do this, Right-click on the drive and select Properties.  Click on the Hardware tab.  Find your USB drive in the list, click on it, then click the Properties button.  On the Policies tab, select the "Optimize for performance" option.  Click OK.  Wait a few seconds for the drive to remount.  Now you will be able to format the drive as NTFS or FAT32.

Comment: I'm curious to know what language that's in.

Comment: @Moshe: It's in Turkish.

Answer (score 3):

> This is done for performance reasons. Windows XP knows nothing about the nature of a removeable disk. In some cases the media may be removed or changed and Windows will know nothing about it. This is the case with Floppy drives. It is all up to the device and it's drivers. Since the media can be changed at any time Windows can not determine the total and free space without actually reading the disk. With some devices this can take some time. This could produce a delay of several seconds (or more) every time you opened Windows explorer. To avoid these possible delays Microsoft decided not to show this information for removeable drives. In most cases there will be no work around. If one exists it would be in the properties for the device shown in Device Manager.

[Source](http://www.thewinforums.com/threads/41783-Why-do-removable-disks-not-show-details-on-free-space-in-explorer-as-normal-disks-do) see post 4

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I give a, I wish, accepted answer...

Regarding the previous comments on the question, we assume that Windows XP can't give the requested information in Mehper's question.

> **Snark**: I suppose it's the behavior of XP not to show free space and total size on Removable Disk. Maybe because at the time XP was released, removable drives were slow and it would take a lot of time to parse them to calculate the used space. Even more on FAT where this info is not stored in the metadata but has to be calculated each time. I think it's stored in the metadata for NTFS. And the speed of removable devices has improved too.
>
> **r0ca**: It's weird. I have Windows 7 as you have and I am able to format my 4go and 16go in NTFS. In that case, I'm 99% sure that have it format in NTFS would fix the issue. But if you can't afford due to Xbox, I understand ;)

Comment: Since Snark said "I didn't find yet literature to back my suppositions", I won't accept this as an answer. Even if he found ground for his judgment, it would be unrighteousness to accept the answer as your name is written under the answer, not his.

Comment: There is a graphic here listing differences between NTFS and all FAT file system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Metadata . I can't tell which one of these is used to display information unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a trick to make Windows XP display USB drive's Total size and Free space in My Computer window?

I'm not sure of any tricks to get the size to show up on those columns, but if you want to be able to see the total sizes of the disk from My Computer, a possible workaround would be to append (or prepend, depending on your preference) the size to the name of the device.

For example, a disk named 'Work' could be renamed to 'Work(8Gb)', 'Work8G' or even '8G Work'

this won't show free space remaining, but at least lets you know how big a drive is when you use it again.

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm late to the game but hopefully this will help someone that's trying to get the "total space" and "free space" parameters on Windows XP (SP3) as I was. Unless I've missed it, my Google search came up with no answers. What I tried (successfully) was to use the portable app "Explorer++" file manager from https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/explorerplusplus_portable. What a neat litte app as is so much that's on this site. I keep a USB stick with all my portable apps.....and any of them can be installed to any folder you desire on your Windows installation. I always make a folder on all of my computers labeled "My Tools". When I say "install"......it's only installed to "My Tools" folder. One last comment about the Explorer++ app.....you will have to add the "total space" and "free space" columns by right-clicking the column heading bar and selecting the desire parameter.

Comment: You might need to be converted to a comment, feel free to flag a mod and ask for this to be done until you earn enough rep to write comments... this is an easy and simple task too by the way.